# AWS LEX V2 -Invocation Source is not changing to FullfillmentCodeHook from DialogCodeHook after receiving value for all required slots

Tags: android, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am building a **multi-lingual bot using LexV2**

For **English - US language**
I have an 3 Intents, *1: Start Conv having 1 slots* (Not Required for intent), **2: Eligibility Determination** having 6 slots (4 required and 2 not for intent), **3: End Conv** having 1 slot (not required for intent)

The same intent I have for English_AU language. The only change is at the end of IntentName, slot name, I have added '_au'.

**Please note I am using same lambda Function file for both languages... attached specifically on each language. Lambda file have different modules for entire conversation flow for each language and a common lambda handler, handling events based on intent name.**

Conversation Flow should be like like this on a high level and straight forward scenario.

Start Conv Intent ----> Eligibility Determination Intent (Required Slots) ----> After Filling required Slots in a FullfillmentCodehook it should Elicit 1 Non required Slot----> End Conv Intent

For English_US the conversation flow is working as expected.

But the problem is for English_AU after fullfilling all the required slots in Eligiblity_Determination_AU Intent, it **should change invocation source to Fullfillment code hook, but it is not, it still keeping invocation source as DialogCodehook** and in console After giving response to last required slot, it shows **Eligiblity_Determination_Intent is ready for fullfillment.**

Can anyone please help me in debugging this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing the below fields in the Json response after the last slot has been filled?

> ```
> "state": "ReadyForFulfillment",
> "confirmationState": "None"
> ```

If so, this means you have not checked the Code Hooks checkbox at the bottom of the intent's configuration page. You need to enable this on a per-intent level.

Comment: thank you. it worked. I have one more question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72494536/same-slot-types-working-differently-on-aws-lex-v1-and-v2 can you please help me in it